# Formatting phone number based on country code

Tags: r, substr

I am working on a shiny app where I want to display telephone numbers of contacts. If the number is a US number, I want to show it in a specific format, for example `(XXX) XXX- XXXX` else I just want to return the number as it is.

I tried the most simple way using `substr`. This is the function I have.

```
telFormat <- function(x){
  if (is.na(x)){
    return ("")
  }
  if(substr(x,1,3) %in% c("+1 ")){
    p1 <- substr(x,4,6)
    p2 <- substr(x,8,10)
    p3 <- substr(x, 12,15)
    return (paste("(",p1,") ",p2,"-",p3, sep = ""))
  }
  else 
    return (x)
}
```

The sample data I have is:

```
sample <- c("+1 312 252 7546", "+1 678 538 1919", "+44 (0) 207 743 4052", 
            "+44 (0) 207 743 3000", "+1 212 810 5300", NA, "+44 (0) 207 591 6630", 
            "+61 2 9272 2200", "+852 3903 2448", "+1 415 670 6267", "+44 (0) 207 743 3000", 
            "+1 212 810 5300", "+1 919 743 2500", "+1 919 743 2500", "+1 919 743 2500", 
            "+1 919 743 2500")
```

The output for the phone numbers starting with `+1` gets converted correctly, but there is something wrong with the other numbers.

```
telFormat(sample)

#output
[1] "(312) 252-7546" "(678) 538-1919" "( (0)  20- 743" "( (0)  20- 743" "
(212) 810-5300" "(NA) NA-NA"     "( (0)  20- 591"
 [8] "( 2 ) 272-2200" "(2 3) 03 -448"  "(415) 670-6267" "( (0)  20- 743" "
(212) 810-5300" "(919) 743-2500" "(919) 743-2500"
[15] "(919) 743-2500" "(919) 743-2500"
```

and I get this warning message too

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (substr(x, 1, 3) %in% c("+1 ")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a efficient way to get the desired output?

Comment: Your function is not vectorized but you are using it as if it is. Instead do: `unname(sapply(sample, telFormat))`

Comment: @Chrisss, thanks. That works!!

Answer (score 0):

If all US numbers in your data have a specific format, i.e. `+1 XXX XXX XXXX`, you can use regex `^\\+1 (\\d{3}) (\\d{3}) (\\d{4})$` to reformat it:

```
sub("^\\+1 (\\d{3}) (\\d{3}) (\\d{4})$", "(\\1) \\2-\\3", sample)

# [1] "(312) 252-7546"       "(678) 538-1919"       "+44 (0) 207 743 4052"
# [4] "+44 (0) 207 743 3000" "(212) 810-5300"       NA                    
# [7] "+44 (0) 207 591 6630" "+61 2 9272 2200"      "+852 3903 2448"      
#[10] "(415) 670-6267"       "+44 (0) 207 743 3000" "(212) 810-5300"      
#[13] "(919) 743-2500"       "(919) 743-2500"       "(919) 743-2500"      
#[16] "(919) 743-2500"
```

---

This uses capture groups with parenthesis to match the first three, second three and last four digits in a US number, refer to these pattern with back references `\\` with a number as replacement.

Comment: The regex might have to be a bit stricter. The question seems to only want US numbers converted into a proper format, with the rest left as-is.

Comment: @Psidom, the problem with this it makes no US numbers look like US numbers and gives incorrect numbers for them. For example, `+44 (0) 207 743 3000` becomes `(207) 743 3000`, so a UK number is now like a US number and for `+61 2 9272 2200` we get a completely different number `(129) 272 2200`

Comment: So you just want to format US numbers? i.e. numbers starting with `+1` and for all other numbers, don't make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

May be somethign like this helps with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(str_match_all(sample[!is.na(sample)], 
        "(\\+1|.*)[^\\d]?(\\d+)[^\\d]+(\\d+)[^\\d]+(\\d+)$"), function(x) x[,2:5])))


            V1  V2   V3   V4
1           +1 312  252 7546
2           +1 678  538 1919
3  +44 (0) 20    7  743 4052
4  +44 (0) 20    7  743 3000
5           +1 212  810 5300
6  +44 (0) 20    7  591 6630
7        +61     2 9272 2200
8         +85    2 3903 2448
9           +1 415  670 6267
10 +44 (0) 20    7  743 3000
11          +1 212  810 5300
12          +1 919  743 2500
13          +1 919  743 2500
14          +1 919  743 2500
15          +1 919  743 2500
```

Comment: How is the output different from the input? It looks the same to me

Comment: @krish now you can work on the output dataframe with the 4 columns separated out and reformat (add parenthesis) as you want, does it help?